# Google Fit integration issue in Android

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I got this error while integrating Google Fit in Android:

> Connection failed. Cause:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,
>   resolution=PendingIntent{3162627d: android.os.BinderProxy@2a943572}}

LogCat:

> 12-11 12:21:00.207
>   21307-21307/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi
>   I/BasicHistoryApi: Ready 12-11 12:21:00.266
>   21307-21307/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi
>   I/BasicHistoryApi: Connecting...
>
> 12-11 12:21:01.369
>   21307-21307/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi
>   I/BasicHistoryApi: Connection failed. Cause:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,
>   resolution=PendingIntent{3162627d: android.os.BinderProxy@2a943572}}
>
> 12-11 12:21:01.376
>   21307-21307/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi
>   I/BasicHistoryApi: Attempting to resolve failed connection

Comment: Error says sign in required. Did you sign in? Where is your code? Also the logcat

Comment: @cricket_007 i used this tutorial https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started . Log cat only shows this line which i mention above.

Comment: Okay, so what step of the tutorial are you stuck on?

Comment: @cricket_007 i have done it all thing but when i execute the app then connection is failed and above logcat is shown each time.

Comment: Is there an active Google account signed into on the device? Maybe not relevant, but are you running this in an emulator?

Comment: i try to run on device and account is working.

Comment: Hmm, not really sure what else to ask without doing the tutorial as well. I looked up the error and all it says is "The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in."

Comment: How to resolve this problem any idea?

Comment: some typo and formatting

Answer (score 1):

i just had the same problem.
Go to developer console, create new Project,
-> API Maqnager -> Credencials -> new Credentials -> OAuth cielnt ID
select Android and and set your fingerprint and package name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate Outh2 Client fron google ai console with your package name and SHA1 HAsh key of your IDE